# Making php very fast on shared hosting

Tags: php, optimization

im using shared hosting and would like to use some kind of opcache library like eaccelerator etc. The problem is i have no permissions to install some of these on server. im looking for some way of optimizing php without having to use PEAR/installing etc. has anyone been able to optimize php on shared hosting and if so, how did you do it. im open to all answers. thanx

Answer (score 4):

**Buy a cheap VPS, *if your site is worth it*.**

There are plenty of them available for $15-$25 per month.

Comment: And don't use eAccellerator but APC. APC is the future, XCache and eAccellerator are the past.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PEAR is a thing you don't need to install.
Despite of it, PEAR can't help you with "Making php very fast" because it's merely a library of code snippets.

Opcode caching can make php code fast, yes. But I really doubt it's PHP code itself make your site works slow.

Comment: okay, i have done some profiling and have found out that the scripts are running slow when logged in (sessions and jquery get) any reasons as to why

Comment: @Sir logged in what? when users logged in? I'd profile further then, this session management part

Comment: i use sessions and cookies to determine if user is logged in. the problem is the big difference in time when same script is run when logged in and when logged out

Comment: @Sir I'd suggest you to ask another question, because this matter is far away from your current one. It would be much better if you gather as much information as possible, because it's quite hard to answer a question "my sessions are slow".